# Why does my console return this instead of loggin my data to mailchimp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, http-post, mailchimp

Here im trying to post my data to mailchip list from a simple form i made.
Im using body-parser to parse the data and assign it to "const"s
THen following the api doc "BATCH SUBSCRIBE OR UNSUBSCRIBE" im making a js object to store the body of the data im gonna send. after that I stringify it.

I make post request using https the url is my mailchip list , the method is "POST" and i do my authenticaion using my_string and my_api_key, then a callback function is initiated.i make it a const and then write data to the request and end it.

```
app.post("/",function(req,res){
    const fName = req.body.first_name;
    const lName = req.body.last_name;
    const email = req.body.email;

    // res.write("First Name : "+fName);
    // res.write("Last Name : "+lName);
    // res.write("Email : "+email);
    // res.send();

    const data =
        {
          members:
            [
                {
                    email_address: email,
                    status: "subscribed",
                    merge_fields:
                    {
                     first_name: fName,
                        last_name: lName
                    }
                }
            ]     
        }   

    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

    const url = "https://{api-server}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list_id}";

    const options = {
        method:"POST",
        auth: "{my_string}:{my_api_key}"
    }


    const request = https.request(url, options, function(response){
        response.on("data",function(data){
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        })
    })

    request.write(jsonData);
    request.end();


})
```

I tried running this code from my vs code terminal by using " nodemon app.js " on my localhost:#### <- port num.

I expected it to work fine and log my data to my MAILCHIMP's List.

[Update : i modified my "request.end;" to "request.end(); BUT I got this error instead]
:

```
undefined:1
{"new_members":[{"id":"2f0285dfb0337da7ddbc581a5452fd06","email_address":"buchu@luyu.com","unique_email_id":"5b4586e19a","email_type":"html","status":"subscribed","merge_fields":{"FNAME":"","LNAME":"","ADDRESS":"","PHONE":"","BIRTHDAY":""},"stats":{"avg_open_rate":0,"avg_click_rate":0},"ip_signup":"","timestamp_signup":"","ip_opt":"202.51.69.32","timestamp_opt":"2023-12-09T06:40:27+00:00","member_rating":2,"last_changed":"2023-12-09T06:40:27+00:00","language":"","vip":false,"email_client":"","location":{"latitude":0,"longitude":0,"gmtoff":0,"dstoff":0,"country_code":"","timezone":""},"tags_count":0,"tags":[],"list_id":"bd9a1eb732","_links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https://us21.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{my_list_id}/members/2f0285dfb0337da7ddbc581a5452fd06","method":"GET","targetSchema":"https://us21.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Definitions/Lists/Members/Response.json"},{"rel":"parent","href":"https://us21.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{my_list_id}/members","method":"GET","targetSchema":"https://us21.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Definitions/Lists/Members/CollectionResponse.json","schema":"https://us21.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Paths/Lists/Members/Collection.json"},{"rel":"update","href":"https://us21.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{my_list_id}/members/2f0285dfb0337da7ddbc581a5452fd06","method":"PATCH","targetSchema":"https://us21.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0

SyntaxError: Unterminated string in JSON at position 1371
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (F:\Projects\newsletter-signup\app.js:56:30)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:758:10)
    at flow (node:internal/streams/readable:1248:53)
    at resume_ (node:internal/streams/readable:1227:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

Comment: `request.end;` is missing `()` to call the function: `request.end();`

Comment: Hello can you try to look at it after the update ?

Comment: When you get a `data` event, it doesn't contain the entire message. You have to concatenate `data` to a buffer. When you get the `end` event you can then parse the buffer. You need to read a tutorial on using the `requests` module.